# How to add conditions to a query

Tags: sparql

I would like to add a condition to a query, so that, if a result is empty, it fills it with a result of another query.

For example : If a owl:Class has no "skos:definition", I would like to replace it by a "rdfs:comment"

Is this possible ?

Thank you !

Comment: `select ?class ?description { ?class a owl:Class . optional { ?class skos:definition ?definition } optional { ?class rdfs:comment ?comment } bind (coalesce(?definition, ?comment) as ?description) }`.

Comment: or `bind (if(bound(?definition), ?definition, ?comment) as ?description)`.

Comment: Oups... didn't see the answers... Ok for the BIND solution. Thank you all !

Answer (score 2):

`COALESCE` is can help, especially as you get more choices from `skos:prefLabel`, `skos:altLabel` and more.

```
OPTIONAL { ?property rdfs:label ?label }
OPTIONAL { ?property skos:definition ?definition .}
# ... other ways to choose ?comment ...
BIND ( COALESCE(?definition, ?label, "Unknown") AS ?comment )
```

`COALESCE` allows expressions (unlike `BOUND`)

https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce

Answer (score 1):

I found something with `BIND (IF(BOUND(...) ..., ...) AS ...)` statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?type ?property ?comment ?propertyType ?domain
WHERE {
    ?property rens:hasAttributeType ?propertyType .
    ?property rens:hasForDomain ?domain .
    ?property rdf:type ?type .
    ?property rdfs:label ?label .
    OPTIONAL {?property skos:definition ?definition .}
    BIND(IF(BOUND(?definition), ?definition, ?label) AS ?comment) .
}
```

Is this the better way ?